# Why isn't the future participle more diffuse in modern languages?

Tags: tense, participles

The Ancient Greek had a participle for the future tense, and the only language I know it uses the future tense is Esperanto.

Is there a reason why the future participle appears to be rare cross-linguistically?

Comment: [Lithuanian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithuanian_grammar#The_Future_Tense) has future tense.

Comment: [Hungarian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_verbs#Participles) also has a future participle in andó/-endő.

Comment: As does [Turkish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_language#Attributive_verbs_.28participles.29). None of these three are particularly closely related, I'd say your premise seems to be incorrect.

Comment: By "modern languages" do you mean Modern European languages? You might want to edit this question to make that clearer.

Comment: @LaurenG By modern languages I mean languages spoken nowadays. There are language families that don't use the future participle; that happens also in non European languages.

Comment: Latin has a future participle too. And many other languages have composite or periphrastic future participles, like Dutch *zullende komen, zullende lachen,* etc.

Comment: @Cerberus Latin is not what I would call "modern language"; it's an official language in just a state, and it is not commonly used in normal conversations.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I didn't say it was: it just seemed a relevant fact.

Comment: @Cerberus It surely is, when you consider languages derived from Latin, without the future participle, and you wonder why they have not inherited it from Latin. It is just confusing to mix Latin with other languages spoken nowadays.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Quite the opposite, the fact three related languages do use the future participle doesn't mean other languages have it too. It would be like comparing Dutch, German, and English, and say they are representative of other languages.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: What do you mean by "mix"? Where did I do that? By the way, your second question isn't even about modern languages specifically.

Comment: @Cerberus In your comment you are referring to Latin, and Dutch; other comments report languages using the future participle that are spoken nowadays. My question is about languages spoken nowadays; I am not asking why Ancient Greek had the future participle, and another language that is not anymore spoken didn't have it.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Even so, Latin influenced certain modern languages a great deal, so it would seem relevant for your question to analyse the Latin participle too. I wasn't answering your question: it was just a comment.

Comment: @kiamlaluno perhaps you read my comment wrong? The examples were of three *unrelated* languages, Turkish, Lithuanian, Hungarian. This actually is evidence that the future participle *is* diffuse.

Comment: @MarkBeadles I simply read "are closely related," instead of "not closely related." Even so, I can take you three other languages that don't use the future participle, and say that the future participle is not diffuse. Also, the title says, "isn't the future participle more diffuse"; I am not saying it is not diffuse, but I am asking why it is not more diffuse, or why there are languages using it, and languages not using it.

Comment: @klamlaluno, what may be hindering our discussion is that I read "diffuse" as meaning "spread across many linguistic families", not as meaning "common". I thought you were asking the former.

Comment: @Cerberus That's fine, but you didn't say so, in your first comment.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: But what else could I have meant?

Comment: Latin forms the future participle of most verbs (futurus, moriturus), Russian only form the verb to be (будущий).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's say that a future participle is a non-finite form of a verb which is marked for future tense. For a language to have a chance of having a future participle, there must be:

1. Verbal inflection for tense in addition to some other category, viz. subject agreement
2. A process for forming non-finite forms

These two requirements will narrow down the set of candidate languages quite significantly. Looking at the languages that meet these criteria, the question is whether it is more common for non-finite verb forms of this type to have neither subject nor tense marking, or to have one or the other, and whether it is more common for non-finite verbs to be marked only for subject agreement or only for tense when they are marked for at least one category. So what is more common? Tensed forms without subject marking, as in present, future, past participles; OR Tenseless forms with subject marking, as in the Portuguese "personal infinitives."

Some interesting possibly relevant data comes from Cristofaro (2007: 112), where a survey is made of marking on verbs in dependent clauses. What is found is that when subject or object agreement is not expressed on the verb, tense/aspect/mood tends not to be marked either.

```
                                T/A/M not expressed    T/A/M expressed

Arguments not expressed                127                49
Arguments expressed                    117                150
```

What I have no intuitions about is whether in non-finite verb forms which are tensed but lack agreement marking, there should be a reason for some tenses not to be expressed (e.g., future) when others (e.g., past) can be expressed.

Cristofaro, S. (2007) "Deconstructing categories: finiteness in a functional-typological 
perspective." in Nikolaeva, I. ed. *Finiteness*. OUP, pp.91--114.